# storing integer and char in an array

Tags: c, arrays

Objective:-To print A3B5 as shown below..
AAABBBBB

I have achieved this through following code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(){

    char char1[2],*ptr_char,c;
    int  number[2],*ptr_number,i,j=0,k=0;

    ptr_char = char1;
    ptr_number = number;

    printf("Enter character string\n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        scanf("%c",&char1[i]);

    printf("Enter number array\n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        scanf("%d",&number[i]);

    for(i=0;i<ptr_number[j];i++)
        printf("%c",ptr_char[k]);

    j++;
    k++;

    for(i=0;i<ptr_number[j];i++)
        printf("%c",ptr_char[k]);

    getch();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Now i have to take a single array in which my A3B5 can be taken instead of taking two array.

But i am unable to take array like that.

I want to take A3B5 in single array .
Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you do `scanf("%s", string);` where `string` is `char string[5];` After that you can parse the input string for numbers and characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say:

```
char csrc[]= "A3B5" ;
```

The issue here is that 3 and 5 are not numbers, they are characters.  So you will have to convert from "3" to 3.  You have several options for that, including `sscanf` and `atoi`.  As others have suggested, read in the entire string at once, and it will be in the `char` array, and then decompose it into the separate parts you want.

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        int count = 0, i = 0;
        char temp = 0;
        char ip[16] = {0};
        char filter[8] = {0};
        int num[8] = {0};
        printf("Enter input :\t");
        scanf("%s", ip);
        for (count = 0, i =0; count < strlen(ip); count++, i++)
        {
                filter[i] = ip[count];            //take out the character to print
                count++;
                temp = ip[count];                 //read the number of print iteration as a character
                num[i] = atoi(&temp);             // convert "n" [charater] to n [int]
        }
        for (count = 0; count < strlen(ip)/2 ; count++)
        {                                             //print loop
                for (i = 0; i < num[count]; i++)
                        printf("%c\t", filter[count]);
                printf("\n\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Sample run and o/p

```
[sourav@localhost test]$ ./a.out 
Enter input :   S2G5
S   S   
G   G   G   G   G   
[sourav@localhost test]$
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some comments, or an explanation?

Comment: @ldrumm what kind of comments?

Comment: I mean that just posting code may not help the OP understand *why* you have posted the code you did.  Adding source code comments, or an explanation may help clarify their reasoning and in turn, become better at solving problems like this themselves.

Comment: @ldrumm sure. Will do.

Comment: @Jack13 good to hear that. Just FYI, this is a sample code with no error-case check. if you want a robust code , please add the check for complex scenarios. you can use `isalpha()` or `isdigit()` to acomplish that.

Comment: @Jack13 and if this works for you, don't forget to accpet the answer. ;-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh:- i m done with functions mentioned by u.. its working...                  Can i get ur mail id?

Comment: @Jack13 actually I'm not sure whether its allowed or not to write down a mail ID here. You check my SO profile. From there you'll get some link to contact me.